# Lines above and below overlap

Tags: html, css

I am still learning, but I have learnt enough to do HTML and implement some of the things that have been told on stackoverflow about HTML codes CSS and JavaScript. For the webpage http://www.cure4incurables.com/fibroids.htm the lines (above and below) overlap when seen on a mobile device but it is fine on a desktop or laptop. Please tell me how to correct it. Please also let me know how to make the links at the bottom just above the footer to have a background color which extends to 100% of the width of the screen

Comment: please consider reading [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: By overlap, do you mean they overflow the width of the viewport, creating a horizontal scrollbar?

Answer (score 0):

Increase the `line-height` for the element you want to increase the distance between lines. Like:

```
line-height:30px;
```

for more info: [line-height CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height)

Comment: I had not used a "line-height" https://stackoverflow.com/users/8700522/cedverd and I added it to each individual paragraph (whatever begins with <p> and it is fine now). I was also able to make the links at the bottom to fill the screen from left to right by altering a div above to make it have a width of 100%. Thanks to all of you for answering.